# Did this character's name change in various printings of Heinlein's "—We Also Walk Dogs"?

Tags: character-identification, robert-a-heinlein

In Robert A. Heinlein's "*[—We Also Walk Dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%80%94We_Also_Walk_Dogs)*" (1941), the opening scene has an operator at a company which does various tasks for people, businesses, and governments take a call.  The woman calling identifies herself as Mrs. "Von Hogbein-Johnson", and the operator knows from the name that she is super rich.

Mrs. Von Hogbein-Johnson gives a personal name - not hers, but that of her husband.  I remembered her saying she was "Mrs. **Rufus** Von Hogbein-Johnson".  But sometime later I was looking at "—We Also Walk Dogs" in various anthologies and Heinlein collections and I think I remember her as calling herself "Mrs. **Peter** Von Hogbein-Johnson"  and/or "Mrs. **Oscar** Von Hogbein-Johnson".

I think that a writer might change various details in a story from time to time for copyright reasons, so I wonder how many personal names Mr. Von Hogbein-Johnson might have in different versions of this story.

I guess it would take a real super-fan to own (or have access to) [every single reprinting](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46427), but I'm guessing that between us we might be able to check each copy.

Comment: She is Mrs. Peter van Hogbein Johnson in the July 1941 *Astounding* https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v27n05_1941-07_dtsg0318-LennyS/page/n125/mode/1up

Comment: @user14111 - Google Books has no record of the other versions of the name (aside from Peter) and nor does a keyphrase search on Google.

Comment: It's still Peter in my copy ($1.95 Signet paperback) of *The Green Hills of Earth*. For a possible explanation of this mystery see Larry Niven's "For a Foggy Night". https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v041n01_1971-07_PDF/page/n65/mode/1up

Comment: It's also "Mrs Peter van Hogbein Johnson" in my copy of *The Past Through Tomorrow, Vol. 2* New English Library, 1977, which appears to be a republishing of the US edition by Berkeley Medallion Books. BTW, they have a son named "Peter III, a slightly shop-worn Peter Pan". :)

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Hogbein-Johnson%22+-peter) has no results without the first name Peter, with other first names (a few without *any* first name though).

Comment: SFBC 1980s edition of TPTT = Peter as well.

Comment: Does Mrs. Hogbein Johnson appear in any other Heinlein stories?

Comment: @user14111  not that I remember.